# Xamarin Forms Shell: Dynamically remove FlyoutFooter

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

It seems as though hiding the FlyoutFooter with IsVisible doesn't cause the scrollview for the Flyout Items to resize to take up the unused space.

Example:

Footer declaration in .xaml:

```
<Shell.FlyoutFooter>
    <StackLayout Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="Pink" HeightRequest="200">
        <Button x:Name="btnCloseTip"
                                    Text="X"
                                    Clicked="btnCloseTip_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Shell.FlyoutFooter>
```

Click handler:

```
    private void btnCloseTip_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var footer = (StackLayout)this.FlyoutFooter;
        footer.IsVisible = false;
    }
```

This hides the pink footer, however the space reserved for the footer is not reallocated to the scrollview that contains the items, leaving a 200 unit high empty space below the scrollable list of flyout items.  Is there any way to force the flyout menu to redraw/resize after hiding?  I have tried setting the layout bounds to a 0,0,0,0 rectangle as well, which also had the same (no-)effect.

Comment: seems a xamarin forms bug you can raise an issue at https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: Thanks.  Still hoping for a workaround though

Comment: As i know, when you set the visable property, it used to hide or show the footer. The footer should be fixed to the bottom of the flyout and not go behind it and obscure the menu items and it still takes any height. I do not find the way to remove the space.